# missing is meta/worthless, time to remove it?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't know who would subscribe to a [missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/missing) tag. I'd be happy to clean up untagged ones afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes

This tag sucks, it should be removed.

Answer (score -3):

## No

I like meaningless tags that add no value to the site and just create noise for people.

Comment: Aren't you stacking the deck a bit? ;)